# Firebase update child Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update child status as Active, but I really do not know how to solve this. I want to update a specific record, I am using table btw. I'm stuck here already. Please help me. Thank you!

```html
<script>
  // Get a reference to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();

  database.ref('Users').orderByChild('usertype').equalTo('Property Owner').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      var content = '';
      snapshot.forEach(function(data) {

        var stat = data.val();
        if (stat.status == 'Inactive') {
          var val = data.val();
          content += '<tr>';
          content += '<td>' + val.fname + '</td>';
          content += '<td>' + val.mname + '</td>';
          content += '<td>' + val.lname + '</td>';
          content += '<td>' + val.email + '</td>';
          content += '<td>' + val.registered + '</td>';
          content += '<td>' + val.status + '</td>';
          content += '<td><button type="button" id="button" style="font-size: 12px;class="btn btn-danger" onclick="myFunction()">Update Status</button></td>';
          content += '</tr>';

        }
      });
    }
    $('#ex-table').append(content);
  });

  function myFunction() {
    alert('');
  }
</script>
```

[This is my json tree in firebase.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYKVI.png)

Comment: What is the output you're getting vs the output you'd like to get?

Comment: There is no output yet. I want to change the status to Active, when I click the button Update Status, It will update the child status to Active. But I know how. @TheCog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, let me take a crack at this, what you're trying to do is update a field. You can find info in the docs on how to do so [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), but essentially what you need to do is build a reference to the specific user you want to modify, and then call update on it. So, in whatever you have listening to the button, you want to do something like

```
firebase.database().ref().update({'users/USERNAME/status': "Active"})
```

Where USERNAME is the name of the specific user you want to update.

Comment: I am getting what you are saying, but my problem is, I do not know how to retrieve the username. I used email address. I cannot fetch the unique id.

Comment: In the json tree example you posted username would be cindygmailcom. You could for example, store the username when you retrieve the user in your table building function using data.$key, and store it in the table, or perhaps if its more convenient hidden in an element associated with that row.

Comment: I will try this one. Thank you for your help! So much appreciated!

Comment: If it works for you please mark the answer as approved by clicking the big check mark! Good luck!